# Cadence Virtuoso Layout XL

Tags: cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I am new to Cadence Virtuoso Layout.Is there any book or complete educational videos for Cadence Virtuoso Layout design? I have some DRC errors on my design and need to know how to solve the errors in different metal layers.

Comment: DRC errors depends on each design and technology size, you need to check with your vendor or find the standard that you are using from your library.

Answer (score 0):

DRC error belongs to Physical Verification, which has many tools support like Assura, Mentor Calibre... To fix the DRC error, you have to read the PDK (Process Design Kit) document.

About the education video for Cadence Virtuoso Layout Design, there is some video on Youtube as far as I know. However, the best way to learn is doing real layout design work. If you have any problem, find the manual of tool in Cadence Help.